# Getting data from Laravel Collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I realize this is a dumb question, but I can't find an answer for it. I am missing some understanding around how collections work

I am querying a google places API for information about a location

```
 $response = GooglePlaces::textSearch('10 Downing Street', $optionnalParameters);
```

This works and gives me a response, which I can var_export:

```
   Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array(
   'items' => 
  array (
    'html_attributions' => 
    array (
    ),
    'results' => 
    Illuminate\Support\Collection::__set_state(array(
       'items' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'formatted_address' => '10 Downing St, London SW1A 2AA, United Kingdom',
          'geometry' => 
          array (
            'location' => 
            array (
              'lat' => 51.503363499999999,
              'lng' => -0.12762480000000001,
            ),
            'viewport' => 
            array (
              'northeast' => 
              array (
                'lat' => 51.503432400000001,
                'lng' => -0.12551999999999999,
              ),
              'southwest' => 
              array (
                'lat' => 51.503156800000014,
                'lng' => -0.12832640000000001,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          'icon' => 'https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/civic_building-71.png',
          'id' => 'ffd85a3e543406e34703ee947c73ef54f5e167fe',
          'name' => '10 Downing Street',
          'photos' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'height' => 2534,
              'html_attributions' => 
              array (
                0 => '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/117230111047681784763/photos">Christopher Chan</a>',
              ),
              'photo_reference' => 'CoQBdwAAAHdqDNRUhalI7Ko_YXqckWM5M7I1IeD0xXOvjnxruS4BYCFnt99lCEy5xQJh7XtTvGTfZbKlnVhbxaJ_OloLxaPyoInqIpgRY-3LyB3Q70tDX3izeraFEM4Bw-ExmRzz6h18iMQlKb0DoDXnW26uO4RR-7YFjPNi6M0y5D7cmrl9EhAmI7GerM-TXpKD3BVVTtOWGhQZotS0ZNI2nK9G7jXxDEyvoQ5IxQ',
              'width' => 3801,
            ),
          ),
          'place_id' => 'ChIJRxzRQcUEdkgRGVaKyzmkgvg',
          'rating' => 3.3999999999999999,
          'reference' => 'CmRSAAAAh-Drhh9G_EW3azxZSikW_jR-ZjI2lhZTw6MfWqh9EiTaCEy4uW2okv_g6QfaKoupoeDu3DpfS6MjIvUvp6cc2uAoLlyH9NbkMrnQg9q3ED3R91OejmAScjRhe8G47kJ1EhD_oYVFakm4n6I27j-8iN6oGhQVH6rv1t6uGQBVVOqy1fCAB17JOg',
          'types' => 
          array (
            0 => 'point_of_interest',
            1 => 'establishment',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )),
    'status' => 'OK',
  ),
))
```

I want to get the formatted_address element from the collection. it appears under the results element, that in turn has a collection under it with elements Items,0,formatted_address.

when i start trying to 'walk down' to the element i require I get index not found for Items
          var_export($response['results']['items']);

so essentially, how am I supposed to interact with collections? i have tried google but most the links  tell me about the extra functions that collections provide and not how to get data from it

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-all explains what you are missing. You want to call

```
->all()
```

on your Collection to return the underlying array represented by the collection.
Than you can access fields in the returned array.

Comment: Awesome, that got me on the right path. much appreciated.